# How to alter my VBA code so it only creates a workbook one time, than a worksheet for every other option

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a VBA code that for each drop down selection it copies the sheet as values creates a worksheet for each option in the drop down list in a new workbook.  The problem is everything seems to be working fine in my code except that for each drop down option it's creating a totally separate workbook.  My drop down selection is like 80 options and can grow.  So I don't need 80 different workbooks.  I need one new workbook with the 80 worksheets for each drop down selection.  How can I alter my code so that it creates a new workbook one time than for each drop down selection is a worksheet in that workbook?

Here's my code

```
Sub Worksheet_Create()

Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim Dashboard As Worksheet

Set Dashboard = Sheets("Business Plans")

For Each cell In Worksheets("dd").Range("$C3:$C75")
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        With Dashboard
        .Range("$A$2").Value = cell.Value
            With ThisWorkbook
                .Worksheets("Business Plans").Copy
                ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End With
    End If
Next cell

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.  when i tested it i found that it accomplished what you are asking for

```
Sub Worksheet_Create()

Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
Set Dashboard = wb1.Sheets("Business Plans")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each cell In wb1.Worksheets("dd").Range("$C3:$C75")
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

        With Dashboard
        .Range("$A$2").Value = cell.Value
            With wb1
                .Worksheets("Business Plans").Copy After:=newWB.Worksheets(1)
                ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    End If
Next cell

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```